# What is the difference between "suspend on lid close" vs "suspend after alt+click on power button in gnome-shell user menu"?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, laptop

My Notebook with Ubuntu 18.04 behaves different on wake-up after suspending by closing the lid or after alt+click on the gnome-shell user menu power button.

Most visible difference is the login behavior: I am using winbind with active directory. Login after suspend with lid-close does often not work or I have to enter the password several times before it gets accepted by the system. After suspending by alt+click on the power button in the gnome-shell user menu the login usually works without problems.

So it looks like there is a difference between both procedures. I would like to fix the login problem on lid-close, for this reason I am asking for the difference between both mechanisms.